# Accessibility: aria-label is not getting announced in span by NVDA

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, nvda

I want to have aria-label in span get announced. I did a lot search, found a solution that add role="img". However, in this way, the "image" word will also be announced. I am wondering if there is a hack way to only announce the aria-label or aria-description for span?

For example, I want "123" to be announced:

`<span aria-description="123">456</span>`

Comment: A role is required on elements that don't have semantic meaning.

Comment: Make sure to select the right answer if it helped you, so that other people can be helped too when they stumble on the same issue

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73647165/how-to-avoid-announce-inner-content-when-using-aria-description/73648695#73648695

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid announce inner content when using aria-description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73647165/how-to-avoid-announce-inner-content-when-using-aria-description)

Answer (score 1):

The `aria-label` is sometimes ignored by some assistive technology if the element you put it on doesn't have any semantic meaning. A `<span>` doesn't have semantic meaning. If you add a [role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#role_definitions) that is appropriate for your description, then it should be read correctly.